# java.net.connectException: Failed to connect to /192.168.0.105:80

Tags: android, kotlin, xampp

I am making an android app using xampp server. When i run the app on a device which android version is 10, it works properly. But another device which android version is 8.1.1 shows an exception. java.net.connectException: Failed to connect /192.168.0.105:80

Comment: Can you post the code that handles your connection task?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.